# XML Replace in c#

Tags: c#, xml, replace

Im trying to use the ReplaceChild function. the code works, and no exceptions are thrown, but when I print XML to the screen it seems as if the function didnt work. the original node is the but not the new one.

```
private void convertClubComp(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XmlNode sessionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Session");
        XmlNode clubsNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Clubs", "");
        XmlNode playerNode = sessionNode.SelectSingleNode("Players").SelectSingleNode("Player");
        XmlNode groupNode = sessionNode.SelectSingleNode("Players").SelectSingleNode("Player").SelectSingleNode("Groups");

        Console.WriteLine(playerNode.Name);

        clubsNode = doc.ImportNode(groupNode, true);
        playerNode.ReplaceChild(clubsNode, sessionNode.SelectSingleNode("Players").SelectSingleNode("Player").SelectSingleNode("Groups"));
        Console.WriteLine(clubsNode.FirstChild.FirstChild.Name);

        Console.WriteLine("!"+playerNode.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.Name);


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the xml file you are parsing, and specify which output you are expecting to get. It's rather difficult to guess what that chain of `NextSibling` is supposed to achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what's happening is when you do the ImportNode() it is replacing your reference to the new node you created with a clone of the other node. I think what you're looking for is something along the lines of this:

```
    private void convertClubComp(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XmlNode sessionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Session");
        XmlNode playerNode = sessionNode.SelectSingleNode("Players").SelectSingleNode("Player");
        XmlNode groupNode = playerNode.SelectSingleNode("Groups");

        Console.WriteLine(playerNode.Name);

        XmlNode clubsNode = doc.CreateElement("Clubs", "");
        foreach (XmlNode child in groupNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            clubsNode.AppendChild(child.CloneNode(true));
        }
        foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in groupNode.Attributes)
        {
            clubsNode.Attributes.Append((attribute.Clone() as XmlAttribute));
        }
        playerNode.ReplaceChild(clubsNode, groupNode);
        Console.WriteLine(clubsNode.FirstChild.FirstChild.Name);

        Console.WriteLine("!" + playerNode.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.Name);

    }
```

On a separate note, don't use SelectSingleNode() or SelectNodes() if you already have a reference. It's really poor practice and in larger systems can kill your performance.